# How to get ` int -> (int -> int)`?

Tags: ocaml

Are the two types: `int -> int -> int` and `int -> (int -> int)` the same?

If I write `let f x = fun y -> x + y + 1`, utop returns `int -> int -> int`. But I want is a function that takes an int as a parameter and then return a function which also takes an int and returns int, i.e., `int -> (int -> int)`

Is there a way to do that?

Also for `(’a * ’b -> ’c) -> (’a -> ’b -> ’c)`, I wrote `let f g = fun a b -> g (a,b)`, but it returns `(’a * ’b -> ’c) -> ’a -> ’b -> ’c`, the parentheses are eliminated. But why?

If a new function is returned as result, will it be anyway curried?

Comment: `->` is right-associative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in lambda-calculus all functions have 1 arguments. Functions that take two arguments (not a tuple) are functions which take 1 argument and return another functions.  If you look at the problem from this point of view you will understand that `->` is right-associative.

Comment: So there is no way to print out type of `int -> (int -> int)`?

Comment: The type expression printer is written not to output redundant parenthese. Try `let f : int -> (int -> int) = (+);;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same. The arrow is a right-associative infix constructor, which is why the parentheses are redundant on the right.

It is perhaps helpful to realise that

```
let f x y z = e
```

is simply syntactic sugar for

```
let f = fun x -> fun y -> fun z -> e
```

Everything else follows form there.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, they are the same.

You can try it out, just type in

```
let f x y = x + y + 1;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# let g = f 1;;
val g : int -> int = <fun>
# let _ = List.map g [1;2;3];; (* would do the same with (f 1) instead of g *)
- : int list = [3; 4; 5]
```

The whole idea is that function are by default curryfied. And as `a -> ( b -> c )` and `a -> b -> c` are equivalent, they are displayed as the lightest type possible.